# DoubleClickBidManager API no data retrieved

Tags: python, google-api, dv360

I've created a project within Google Cloud, enabled DV360 and DoubleClick Bid Manager APIs, created oAuth 2.0 Client IDs and credentials and have dowloaded the JSON client secret which I have attached to my project root. In my python code, I am trying to retrieve data (any data) from a queries.create method then loop until the report status becomes AVAILABLE using `state = query.get('metadata', {}).get('status', {}).get('state')` but the ReportStatus returns blank continuously. This is my python code :

```
import logging
import csv
import time
import urllib.request
import os
import pickle

from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from googleapiclient.discovery import build


API_VERSION = 'v2'
ADVERTISER_ID = '*****'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/doubleclickbidmanager']

# Set up the credentials
creds = None

if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
    with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
        creds = pickle.load(token)
# If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
            '/Users/directory to root', SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
    # Save the credentials for the next run
    with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
        pickle.dump(creds, token)

# Build the doubleclickbidmanager API client
service = build('doubleclickbidmanager', API_VERSION, credentials=creds)


# Set up logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)

# Create a query
query_body = {
    "metadata": {
        "title": "Basic Report",
        "dataRange": {
            "range": "LAST_7_DAYS"
        },
        "format": "CSV"
    },
    "params": {
        "type": "STANDARD",
        "groupBys": ["FILTER_PARTNER"],
        "metrics": ["METRIC_IMPRESSIONS"]
    },
    "schedule": {
        "frequency": "ONE_TIME"
    }
}


try:
    # Run the query
    query_create = service.queries().create(body=query_body).execute()
    print(f'Query creation response: {query_create}')

    query_id = query_create['queryId']

    logging.debug(f'Query ID: {query_id}')

    logging.debug("Query executed")

    # Wait for the report to be generated
    report_available = False
    num_retries = 0
    while not report_available and num_retries < 100:
        try:
            query = service.queries().get(queryId=query_id).execute()
            print(f'Query data: {query}')
            print(f'Query metadata: {query.get("metadata")}')
        except Exception as e:
            print('Error occurred: ', e)

        if 'error' in query:
            logging.error(f'Error in query: {query.get("error")}')

        print(f'Query retrieval response: {query}')

        logging.debug(f'Query status: {query["metadata"]}, query ID: {query["queryId"]}')
        logging.debug(f'ReportStatus: {query.get("metadata", {}).get("status", {})}')

        # Check if report is ready or has failed
        state = query.get('metadata', {}).get('status', {}).get('state')
        if state == 'DONE':
            report_available = True
        elif state == 'FAILED':
            logging.error("Report generation failed.")
            break
        else:
            logging.debug("Waiting 30 seconds before checking again")
            time.sleep(30)
            num_retries += 1

        if not report_available:
            logging.error('Report did not become available after 100 retries. Aborting.')
        else:
            # Get the Google Cloud Storage path for the report
            google_cloud_storage_path = query.get('metadata', {}).get('googleCloudStoragePath', '')

            if google_cloud_storage_path:
                # Download the report as CSV
                report_file_name = 'campaign_overview_report.csv'
                urllib.request.urlretrieve(google_cloud_storage_path, report_file_name)
                print("Report downloaded.")
            else:
                print("Google Cloud Storage path not found for the report.")

except Exception as ex:
    print('Exception occurred during query execution: ', ex)
```

Why is my reportStatus continuously returning blank? I am set as the 'Owner' of the project so permissions wouldn't be an issue. Even if there is no data, the status should surely update? Am I doing something wrong?